# Java Path2D.Double on JPanel are painted with a 'tail'

Tags: java, drawing, jpanel, java-2d, path-2d

I have a strange behaviour when drawing a Path2D on a JPanel. 

Some of the shapes get kind of a tail as you can see on this screenshot:

[image]

When I change the type to Line2D.Double, it is as I'd expect it:

[image]

Here's the code that draws the path / line:

```
Path2D.Double path = new Path2D.Double();
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)this.getGraphics();
for(int i=0; i<geom.size(); i++)
{
    double x = ddGeom.getX(geom.get(i));
    double y = ddGeom.getY(geom.get(i));
    if(i==0)
        path.moveTo(x-draw_center.x, y-draw_center.y);
    path.lineTo(x-draw_center.x, y-draw_center.y);
}
g.draw(path);
```

Do you have an idea where the 'tails' in Screenshot1 come from? I use SDK Version 6.

Thank you very much for your help

Edit: When changing the code snippet to

```
if(i==0)
     path.moveTo(x-draw_center.x, y-draw_center.y);
else
     path.lineTo(x-draw_center.x, y-draw_center.y);
```

most (maybe 75%) of the tails disappear. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: When I've used Path2D, I've not had this problem, and based on your code, I can't see where your problem is. Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org). One thing that strikes me as odd is that you're creating your Path2D inside of your drawing method rather than creating it once and then simply drawing it in the drawing method. Why do it this way?

Comment: These can be due to anti-alias effects, try:  g2d.setRenderingHints(Graphics2D.ANTIALIASING,Graphics2D.ANTIALIAS_ON);

Comment: @whatnick: I'm not saying that you're wrong, but I've not seen anti aliasing do this. A strange Stroke perhaps, but not anti-aliasing.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This is just a simplified version of my code. I create the path as you see it in the code snippet, but the drawing is actually handled by another method. Using the snippet as posted would have a major impact on performance....

Comment: @whatnick Tried adding the folowing line of code graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON); But this did not change anything

Comment: @klib009: have you read the [sscce](http://sscce.org) protocol of which I provided a link in a previous post and in this post? Please do so asap. I can neither compile nor run your small code snippets above, and thus I cannot test your assertion nor modify your code in an attempt to correct. So this is in effect tying my hands and preventing me from having any chance of helping you. It's up to you. If you urgently need our help, then consider putting in the effort of creating a compliant sscce for all of us to test and modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it. Thanks to HovercraftFullOfEels hint 'strange Stroke' I played around with my strokes.
Original stroke:

```
BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(2.0f);
```

Changed to:

```
BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL);
```

With the new Stroke all the 'tails' disappeared. I'm still not understanding why this happens, but if someone has the same problem, this workaround could help.

I'd still be very interested in an explanation for this behaviour.

Thank you for your great help

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing in your first image looks almost like ''miters''. Miters are a way to draw line joins in a path where the two outer borders of the lines that are joined are extended until they intersect and the enclosing area is filled as well.

Is it possible that your geometry contains consecutive points with almost the same coordinates? The following example exhibits the same problem because of the last two points with have almost identical coordinates.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

frame.setSize(300, 300);
frame.setContentPane(new Container() {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
        g2.setRenderingHint(KEY_ANTIALIASING, VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHint(KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

        Path2D.Double path = new Path2D.Double();
        path.moveTo(200, 100);
        path.lineTo(100, 100);
        path.lineTo(101, 100.3);

        g2.draw(path);
    }
});

frame.setVisible(true);
```

[image]